# Definition of zero in monomial ideals

Tags: definition, monomial-ideals

I am studying monomial ideals and I have a problem with this definition:

Let R=A$[X_1.....X_k]$, and:
$$0=(\phi)R $$
How this ideal contains 0?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think its from definition . Every ideal of a ring contains zero , then ideal generated by empty set , contains zero . 
Zero is an ideal of a ring contains empty set , then it contains ideal generated by empty set .